# ImportError: No module named _pickle

Tags: python, import, conda

I am working with this python code which has

```
import _pickle
```

I get a ImportError: No module named _pickle

But I am not able to install either _pickle or pickle using conda or pip install. What is this lib and how to install it?

Comment: `import pickle` ?

Comment: the pickle module is part of the standard library. No need to install it.

Comment: Yeah, just remove the underscore.

Comment: I agree with @MrPyCharm . I tried in my local. In Python 3, both works, `import _pickle` and `import pickle`. In Python 2.7, only `import pickle` works. "Works" means "There is no ImportError"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be

```
import pickle
```

instead of

```
import _pickle
```

In general, don't import anything starting with an underscore unless you know what you are doing. They are mostly some modules that are not supposed to be used directly, and usually have wrappers around them (to make platform independent for eg.).

Answer (score 2):

The pickle module is used for serialization of python objects, for example if you want to write objects to a file. The pickle module is in-built so you don't need to install it. The _pickle version is written in C, and is implemented already in pickle. Just use "import pickle" (without quotes!).